# List the name of division that has the most employees working on projects

Tags: sql, oracle11g

So there are three tables that would be applicable in this statement. The division table, which houses the division name and division id, the workon table which houses the projects and employee ids that correlate to the project, and the employee table that houses the employee id, department id, and name. I'm trying to find the department that has the most employees who work on projects.

This is my code:

```
select distinct 
    (dname) as "Division Name"
from 
    employee e, division d
where 
    d.did = e.did and 
    d.did in (
        select did from employee where empid in (
            select empid from workon having count(pid) >= all(pid)
        )
    )
```

I'm supposed to get the answer "human resources" but I cannot seem to get that answer no matter what code I use.

```
Workon table

PID EMPID   HOURS
3   1   30
2   3   40
5   4   30
6   6   60
4   3   70
2   4   45
5   3   90
3   3   100
6   8   30
4   4   30
5   8   30
6   7   30
6   9   40
5   9   50
4   6   45
2   7   30
2   8   30
2   9   30
1   9   30
1   8   30
1   7   30
1   5   30
1   6   30
2   6   30

Employee Table

EMPID   NAME    SALARY  DID
1   kevin   32000   2
2   joan    42000   1
3   brian   37000   3
4   larry   82000   5
5   harry   92000   4
6   peter   45000   2
7   peter   68000   3
8   smith   39000   4
9   chen    71000   1
10  kim 46000   5
11  smith   46000   1

Division
DID DNAME   MANAGERID
1   engineering 2
2   marketing   1
3   human resource  3
4   Research and development    5
5   accounting  4
```

Comment: It is really great if you can show your tables and expected output in the question..............................................

Comment: Hi, I didn't notice your tables, so I added the answer based on a sample. Hope you can use the sample with your data in it. :) Let me know if it works..

Comment: I don't quite understand what you did in your statement. I'm quite new to this so can you tell me how you did it please?

Comment: Isn't the answer correct? Have you seen the SQLFIDDLE Link? IF YES, could you please mark it so, it will save another members efforts of answering another person who is need as you are :) I will update my answer to explain each step for you.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because I can't tell if the answer is right or not. I'm trying to configure your statement to fit my tables and I can't figure out what goes where. Once I can figure out which attribute refers to which of mine I can let you know.

Comment: You have mentioned that you are **sure** that answer is 'human resources'. So if you look at my sample, you can see the answer max number of projects are worked by employees from Human resources department. That's the same logic applies to yours. Let me use your own data and see.

Comment: Sure my tables are in my question, if you need anything else let me know.

Comment: Hi, my apology as I was away on my full time job ;) Just updated an answer for you. Really hope it helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this reference out please.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3717/1)

```
select d.id, d.name, p.maxcounts
from dept d, 
(select we.dep, max(we.counts) as maxcounts 
 from (select w.eid, count(w.pid) as counts, 
 e.dep as dep from employee e, workon w
where e.id = w.eid
group by e.dep) as we) as p
where d.id = p.dep
;
```

RESULTS:

```
ID      NAME                MAXCOUNTS
111     human resoruces     5
```

### FOLLOWING is the edit based on your own data:

Reference : [SQLFIDDLE_Based_ON_OP_Data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6f88d/1)

There are three ways you can achieve this. Either use the nested selects, save Max(count) into a variable or order data by desc and limit it to 1.

Method 1:

-- using nested select

--**sub query 1** explaining to OP how final answer is derived

```
select e.dep, count(w.eid) as num_emp
from employee e, workon w
where e.id = w.eid
group by e.dep
order by e.dep
;
-- **results of sub query 1:**

DEP     NUM_EMP
1           4
2           5
3           7
4           5
5           3
```

-- **Final nested select query**

```
select ee.dep, dd.name, count(ww.eid)
from employee ee, dept dd, workon ww
where ee.id = ww.eid
and ee.dep = dd.id
group by ee.dep, dd.name
having count(ww.eid) = 
(select distinct max(t.num_emp)
from (select e.dep, count(w.eid) as num_emp
from employee e, workon w
where e.id = w.eid
group by e.dep
order by e.dep)as t)
;
```

**-- results using nested selects**

```
DEP     NAME            COUNT(WW.EID)
3       human resource  7
```

**-- query using a variable**

```
select max(x.num_emp) into @myvar from 
(select e.dep, count(w.eid) as num_emp
from employee e, workon w
where e.id = w.eid
group by e.dep) as x
;


select x.dep, x.name, x.num_emp as num_emp from 
(select e.dep, d.name, count(w.pid) as num_emp
from employee e, workon w, dept d
where e.id = w.eid
and e.dep = d.id
group by e.dep) as x
where x.num_emp = @myvar
;
```

**-- results using variable**

```
DEP     NAME              NUM_EMP
3       human resource    7
```

**-- query using limit 1 with ordered desc table**

```
select e.dep, d.name, count(w.eid) as num_emp
from employee e, workon w, dept d
where e.id = w.eid
and e.dep = d.id
group by e.dep
order by num_emp desc 
limit 1
```

**-- results using order by desc and limit 1:**

```
DEP     NAME              NUM_EMP
3       human resource    7
```

Now when using Method 3, it may or may not matter to you that sometimes there will be two departments with same highest number of employees working in projects. So in that case you may use either nested or variable methods.

**PS I do not have the privilledge to be full time on StackOverFlow, hence sorry for getting back to you late :) **

Comment: You are welcome :-)  since this is the answer, could you please mark it as so. Then system will be updated to save other efforts that can help others like you.